# Игнорирование /n в строке. python

Tags: python

Имеется строка.

```
a = "apples, pears # and bananas\ngrapes\nbananas !apples"
```

Как получить из этой строки список посимвольно и почему \n записывается вместе?

```
result = ['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', 's', ',', ' ', 'p', 'e', 'a', 'r', 's', ' ', '#', ' ', 'a', 'n', 'd', ' ', 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 's', '\', 'n', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'p', 'e', 's','\', 'n', 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 's', ' ', '!', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', 's']
```

Answer (score 6):

Получить очень просто:

```
result = list(a)
```

A `\n` это один символ, даже спецсимвол - перевод строки, разделить не получится.

Comment: Можно экранировать обратный слэш `\\n`

Answer (score 0):

Строка уже является последовательностью. Можно просто обращаться к символу по индексу. Либо, для примера:

```
str = “ abc de” 
result = list(str)
```

\n записывается вместе, потому что обратный слэш используется для экранирования символов(google). Вам нужно экранировать обратный слэш. Например:

```
str1 = “abc \nbc” #слэш не экранирован
str2 = “abc \\nbc” #слэш экранирован
```